# Use enumerate() or zip() to get paired values from dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, enumerate

I came across this piece of code:

```
for i, s_point in enumerate(sampled_dict["points"]):
    s_box = sampled_dict["gt_bboxes_3d"][i]
    continue # i is not needed afterwards
```

I thought of another way to do it:

```
for s_box, s_point in zip(sampled_dict["gt_bboxes_3d"], sampled_dict["points"]):
    continue
```

Which one would be faster?

Is there a more efficient way than these two?

(Does the conclusion depend on the type of involved iterators? Such as, `deque` or `tuple` instead of `list`)

Comment: Try timing each using %timeit and then adding the code in the cell (assuming you are using a jupyter notebook)

Comment: Anyway, that's the typical use case for `zip`, and one should avoid using indices when their value isn't needed. So, go for `zip`!

Comment: zip is also potentially safer for the theoretical case where the two lists are of unequal length. Under such a circumstance the first code fragment could lead to IndexError